# How to Iterate and modify data in dynamic forms with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

When i click on the Add Education button, a new form is created and data replicated from the previous. If i try to  remove the replicate, it clears the previous form fields as well. I also push the new data entered into the data property list but the first item does not have data items.

I can handle this with jQuery through find() function, to get a particular data from the dynamic forms, but i am not to do that in Vuejs.

```
<template>
      <div>
    <form v-if="show">

   <button type="button" variant="success"  @click="addItem">Add Education</button>

  <card class="card-body" style="margin-top: 1rem;" v-for="item in educationForm.education" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <card-title>Educational Qualification</card-title>

    <div class="flex-row">
       <mdb-input label="School Name" v-model="educationForm.education.schoolName" size="lg" required/> 
      <mdb-input label="Year Started" v-model="educationForm.education.yearStart" size="lg" required/> 
      <mdb-input label="Year Ended" v-model="educationForm.education.yearEnd" size="lg" required/> 
      <mdb-input label="Qualification Earned" v-model="educationForm.education.qualificationEarned" size="lg" required/> 
    </div>
  </card>

      <button type="button" variant="primary" @click="saveEducation">Submit</button>
    </form>

     <card class="mt-3" header="Form Data Result">
      <pre class="m-0">{{ educationForm }}</pre>
    </card>



  </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
     data() {

      return {
        educationForm: {
          _id: '',
          education: [{
          schoolName: '',
          yearStart: '',
          yearEnd: '',
          qualificationEarned: ''
          }]

        }
      }
     },
    addItem() {
        this.educationForm.education.push({
          schoolName: this.educationForm.education.schoolName,
          yearStart: this.educationForm.education.yearStart,
          yearEnd: this.educationForm.education.yearEnd,
          qualificationEarned: this.educationForm.education.qualificationEarned
        });
      }
}
</script>
```

I expect the new form not replicate the data of the previous form when the button is clicked. And also the data entered does not add to the first object properties in the list.
How can i iterate the forms to clear the new form fields.

Comment: try using v-model="item.schoolName" instead of v-model="educationForm.education.schoolName"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the following part, the v-model property was wrong:

```
 <mdb-input label="School Name" v-model="item.schoolName" size="lg" required/> 
      <mdb-input label="Year Started" v-model="item.yearStart" size="lg" required/> 
      <mdb-input label="Year Ended" v-model="item.yearEnd" size="lg" required/> 
      <mdb-input label="Qualification Earned" v-model="item.qualificationEarned" size="lg" required/>
```